# TFS 2010 build succeeds but fails to drop build in output folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

In my TFS 2010 build definition, if I have the setting CLEAN WORKSPACE = ALL, the directory (c:\builds\Binaries) on the TFS agent machine is deleted. While the build itself succeeds, its output fails to drop to the specified drop location. (The error: "TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory c:\builds\Binaries exists and that you have the appropriate permissions.")

If (after first recreating the c:\builds\Binaries directory) I set CLEAN WORKSPACE = NONE, the build still runs successfully, without getting the drop error. However,  there is still no build output, even though the setting DropBuild = True.

Why would the CLEAN WORKSPACE setting delete a directory without recreating it? Is there another setting used to recreate this directory on the build agent? Is there a downside to using CLEAN WORKSPACE = NONE?  And when I use CLEAN WORKSPACE = NONE, and have a successful build, any ideas why the build is not being dropped to the output location, even though DropBuild = True? (Note that the build log does successfully drop to this location.)

Nothing is ever placed in c:\builds\Binaries during a successful build, even though I've opened up full permissions for everybody on that directory of the build agent server.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I experience similar issue when "Project to Build" path under "Process" is different from "Source Control Folder" of "Workspace" section.

The problem going away as soon as I changed the path to make sure they are match.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I changed DefaultTemplate workflow and it is working now. What I did:

1. I removed all occurrences of BinariesDirectory parameter from DefaultTemplate.
2. Update MatchPattern parameter for FindMatchingFiles activity
3. Update BinariesRoot parameter for GetImpactedTests activity